# Making a copy of an existing Luis app

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I'm working with the Microsoft.Bot.Builder samples and I'm trying to get the AlarmBot to work with Luis. I found a set of app and secret keys to get it running but they're not working as it seems too many people are using them. I'm getting a 403 error. What I'd like to do is make a copy of the exiting Luis App that supports the AlarmBot and import it into my instance of Luis.

Regardless of the AlarmBot sample we're going to need to be able to make copies of Luis Apps to employ a development process. We'll need dev, test, pre-prod, and production instances of the Apps.

Answer (score 1):

In general, with LUIS you can take any app that you've created in LUIS, Export it, and then re-import it as a new app.

For the AlarmBot samples we just use the Cortana app model available in the LUIS portal.  You can create your new app using that and point the alarmbot sample to it.

Comment: Im interested in creating a copy of my LUIS app by exporting and importing. On the import side I get errors like "BadArgument: The application version tokenizer version must be the same as the application tokenizer version.". Can you explain or link to an explination of how to export and import LUIS apps.